# ASP.NET web setup class is not defined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, deployment, web-deployment-project

I've got an ASP.NET application that I installed by creating a web setup. I ran into a problem where ASP.NET wasn't registered with IIS so it gave me a "installation was interrupted" message that told me exactly nothing. Anyhow, I finally got it installed, and I can access the main page, but it's telling me that my class isn't defined. The dll is in the same directory as the Default.aspx page

Here's the main error information

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'SIValidator.SIValidator' is not defined.

Source Error:     

Line 4:  
Line 5:  <script runat="server">
Line 6:      Dim validator As New SIValidator.SIValidator()
Line 7:      Protected table As New arrayList()
Line 8:      Protected countyByDistrict As New Hashtable()

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.1873; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433
```

Am I doing it wrong? Is there some obscure setting that may not be set? I'm completely new to this VS deployment deal, so I'm trying to learn the right terms to ask the right questions... Thanks for any help

edit:
As an aside, when I searched google 5 minutes later, this entry came up as the first result. Would have been awesome if there was an answer for me then :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can either

1. create a bin directory beneath the directory with your web.config and put the assembly in there; you may then need a `<@ Import Namespace="SIValidator" @>` directive in your page but I think the full class name / namespace will work too
2. add your assembly to web.config's [assemblies section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37e2zyhb%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Ah, the #1 was correct, though it needs to be `<%@ Import Namespace="SIValidator" %>`